# How to set SkyDrive Pro Database to another SQL Server instance in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, onedrive

In Skydrive Pro of Sharepoint 2013, how can I set the database to another DB?

In order to reduce loading of SQL Server, we want to set users' personal SkyDrive Pro data to another SQL server, but i am not sure how to do that.  Can anyone give me some tips?

Answer (score 0):

The SkyDrive Pro data of your users is actually stored in a document library in each personal site collection. Personal site collections are located in a content database. From central administration you can find out what content databases are connected to which SharePoint web application. Depending on your setup, you either have the personal sites in the same web application as your other site collections, or which is something you see most of the time, you have a separate SharePoint web application taking care of the personal sites/mysites.

You can add a new content database to a web application, and specify on which server it should reside. Then you can move personal site collections from one content database to the new content database (with PowerShell: Move-SPSite). Alternatively, if you have dedicated content database already setup for the personal sites, you can detach/unmount the content database from the web application, move the actual database to a different SQL server, and mount the content database back to the web application.

It goes a bit beyond the scope of this reply how to perform these steps, but it should give you some pointers on how to go forward.